# Thread Sleep While processing JMS messages

Tags: java, multithreading, jms

My process is listening to a JMS Topic. As and when it receives the message, I am processing it and adding it to a List.
Say

```
  List<ProcessedMessage>
```

I have to send this list to an XMLGenerator. 
But I want to wait/sleep for 5 mins before I do so.

After 5 mins, whatever is the size of my List does not matter. I want to forward it to the XMLGenerator method.

Will a Thread.sleep(5*60*1000) be safe or will it put every single Thread to sleep which will carry the message and wake up all those threads after 5 mins of their sleep ? 
I am not sure if that will be the main Thread. 
Please help.

Comment: Might be a job for ExecutorService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sleep() in JMS messages processing code is really not a good idea. It would tie up connection resources and you are very likely to run into one of the timeouts (e.g. transaction or connection timeout) so it won't work for long delays.

The better implementation would be to have separate class which would hold your list of messages (MessagesCollector), which you would have only one instance of. Your JMS message processing code would add message to MessagesCollector and return successfully right away. Then you can have separate method in MessageCollector which will be triggered by timer every 5 minutes which would grab whatever number of messages had been collected so far and send them to your XMLGenerator, clearing collection afterwards. Just make sure to handle synchronization correctly in MessageCollector implementation.

MessageCollector signature could look something like this:

```
public MessageCollector {
  public synchronized void addMessage(Object message);
  public synchronized void sendCollectedMessages();
}
```

In the code above JMS processing code would call addMessage() and timer would call sendCollectedMessages()

Comment: Thanks this makes me think maybe I can use the springframeworks Scheduled service 
  org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

Comment: If you're using Spring that would be quite appropriate

Answer (score 1):

The Java EE restrictions state that you should not manage threads yourself.

I suggest using javax.ejb.TimerService.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep will only put the current thread to sleep not all threads.

In your case you should definitely not put the Thread.sleep in the onMessage call back.

Some Timer Service would probably be the way to go. Alternatively you can easily instantiate a thread which sleeps and then sends the messages. As stated in other answers be careful of concurrency when emptying the list of messages which can be being written to at the same time.